# How to find cipher keywords in ssh_config(5)

Tags: ssh, sftp, manpage

I see in the man page for ssh that I can find the cipher listings in "ssh_config(5)"

Where can I find this?

Context:
I'm attempting to ssh \ sftp into a company's sftp account that they provided me. What I receive back is the following message:

"Unable to negotiate with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XX: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc"

I'm assuming changing my cipher to aes 256-cbc will solve my issue.

Kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you to look for the `ssh_config` pages, in section `5` of the online manual i.e. `man 5 ssh_config`:

> ```
>  Ciphers
>          Specifies the ciphers allowed for protocol version 2 in order of
>          preference.  Multiple ciphers must be comma-separated.  If the
>          specified value begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified
>          ciphers will be appended to the default set instead of replacing
>          them.
>
>          The supported ciphers are:
>
>                3des-cbc
>                aes128-cbc
>                aes192-cbc
>                aes256-cbc
>                aes128-ctr
>                aes192-ctr
>                aes256-ctr
>                aes128-gcm@openssh.com
>                aes256-gcm@openssh.com
>                arcfour
>                arcfour128
>                arcfour256
>                blowfish-cbc
>                cast128-cbc
>                chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
>
>          The default is:
>
>                chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,
>                aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,
>                aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,
>                aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
>
>          The list of available ciphers may also be obtained using the -Q
>          option of ssh(1) with an argument of “cipher”.
> ```

As noted therein, you could also use `ssh -Q cipher`:

```
$ ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
blowfish-cbc
cast128-cbc
arcfour
arcfour128
arcfour256
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Also it worked perfect. I was able to access the sftp. Cheers mate!!